# Is it okay to remove the [java] tag from Kotlin questions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Can we assume that if a question is specifically about Kotlin, the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag is not needed?

It's worth pointing out that leaving just the [kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin) tag won't cause confusion regarding other non-JVM (Java Virtual Machine) related kotlins (which don't really exist to the best of my knowledge).

Also, while some questions may be answered by a Java developer, we're talking about two different languages that happen to run on the same Virtual Machine. So not all Kotlin question are of interest or can be answered by a Java developer (that's why I'm asking about questions "specifically about Kotlin").

Comment: "What's the difference between XY in Java and Kotlin?"

Comment: There's perfectly valid questions where both apply, so it really depends on the context.